# Amazon S3 Notification services , what is value need to provide for SNS topic ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

While subscribing to the S3 notification , I am creating event but when I am selecting the value of Sendto option as SNS topic  and providing the SNS topic Url it is throwing error always . The value of the SNS topic url provides by me is arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:merge-poc-praveen.

**Error Thrown is :
The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema**  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmSHm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using either objectcreated(all) or put+complete multipart upload Events, but not both at the same time.

I also see a dot at the end of your topic arn - is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this By following the below mentioned steps :
1)First create Topic in AWS .
2) Attach that topic to SNS then it will work fine .
I got the notification after setting the topic and got the notification in email .